# Qt - SplitLayout Issue

Tags: qt, layout, pyqt4

I have got a problem laying out my UI with Qt Designer.
Here is a screenshot of my project, the expected behaviour should be a fixed index on top and the TableWidget that occupy all the space avaible in the StackedWidget. The StackedWidget should be resizable.

[image]

I tried with a VerticalSplit Layout but for some reason it collapse everything and when i preview it, the table look all collapsed and way down where it should be. I'm pretty sure this is the way to go, but can't find out what goes wrong.  Here is a picture of the preview with the VerticalSplit:

[image]

Any suggestion?

Comment: Try setting a layout to your `contactsPage` widget.

Comment: there is no layout to set for contactsPage (that is a StackedWidget), or at least nothing i can make sense with.

Comment: `contactsPage` is a `QWidget` type. You can set a layout to it. Just add something inside it then right click it and select layout from the drop-down list.

Comment: Ok, i tried to apply a layout to the QWidgets and now it works like a charm! Thanks you very much! (how can i set this to the correct answer?)

Comment: I posted an answer that you can accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a layout to your `contactsPage` widget.

Just add something inside it then right click it and select layout from the drop-down list.

Answer (score 0):

So the fields you may like to check are `sizePolicy` in the designer

check the docs for details:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#sizePolicy-prop

You can set the behaviour of the widgets in the layout.
The layout will than respect this. Ich you like a differnt behaivour on resize you may want to go with: `columnStretch` provided by QGridLayout.

Hope this helps,

Comment: i'm trying to change the sizePolicy of both the StackedWidget and TableWidget but no combination seems to work. It just don't resize at all